# How to access to an specific attribute of an object in a python class?

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, reference

Hello I am trying to build a class to clean a string, however I dont understand why I got the following output:

```
 python3 clean.py 
<bound method clean_string.split_func of <__main__.clean_string object at 0x7fb70486b0f0>>
```

My class looks as follows:

```
class clean_string:

    def __init__(self,cadena):
        self.replace_chars = {"á":"a","ó":"o"}
        self.cadena = cadena
    def split_func(self):
        return self.cadena.split(' ')

test_string = clean_string('this is a test')
```

However when I execute the code I only got the memory reference object:

```
print(test_string.split_func)
<bound method clean_string.split_func of <__main__.clean_string object at 0x7fb70486b0f0>>
```

I want to get the following output:

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(test_string.split_func)`

This line prints what split_func is, which is a function. If you want to print what is returned by the function, you need to do 
 `print(test_string.split_func())`

Without the parentheses at the end, it will print what split_func is, which is what you see.